# UIProgressView starts flickering when switching between ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, progress-bar, afnetworking

I have a progress bar (UIProgressView) that shows the progress off an event and when I stay on the view from when it starts, there is no issue.

However when I switch to an other VC and back again, the progress bar flickers.

I am downloading a file with AFNetworking - in case it makes a difference:-)

Is there a way to prevent this from happening??

This is the code for the cell in which the UIProgressView resides

```
    [_operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead)
 {
     float progress = ((float)totalBytesRead) / totalBytesExpectedToRead;
     //NSLog(@"PROGRESS - %f", progress); //Can be deleted once the progress bar works.

     _jwkCell.progressView.progress = progress;

     _jwkCell.progressView.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

 }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it

I just added a check to see if the Float was returning was returning a value other than 0, so it would duplicate the download

```
    if(_jwkCell.progressView.progress == 0)
{
    [self temp];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Is Something Downloading??");
}
```